# How can I convert this for loop into a while loop?

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to adapt this for loop:

```
    $nombresArreglo = ['John','Bruce Lee','Bill Gates','Pedro','Juan','Maria','James    Gosling','Andres'];

    $nombre = 'Bill Gates';

    $resultado = false;

    $i=2;

    for ($i = 0;$i < count($nombresArreglo); $i++){ 

        if ($nombresArreglo[$i] == $nombre){
        $resultado = true;
        break;
        }
    }

    if ($resultado == true){
        echo $nombre . ' found!';
    }
    else{
    echo $nombre. ' doesnt exists';
    }
```

to this one:

```
    while ($i < count($nombresArreglo)){

        if ($nombresArreglo[$i] == $nombre){
            $resultado = true;
            break;
        }    
        if ($resultado == true){
            echo $nombre . ' found';
        }
    }
```

But i can't find the way to make it works. It gives me an empty page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not incrementing the `$i`. Put `$i++` before the end of the loop. And check if `$resultado == true` outside the loop.

Comment: Also, initialize `$i` before entering the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the simple control structure, initialize first, then while is the condition, and dont forget to increment. You forget initialization and the increment. An example:

```
$nombresArreglo = ['John','Bruce Lee','Bill Gates','Pedro','Juan','Maria','James Gosling','Andres'];
$nombre = 'Bill Gates';
$resultado = false;
$i = 0; // <-- you forget initilize
while($i != sizeof($nombresArreglo)-1) { // <-- condition
    if($nombresArreglo[$i] == $nombre) {
        echo $nombre . ' found! at index ' . $i;
        $resultado = true;
    }
    $i++; // <-- you forget increment
}
```

Output will be like: `Bill Gates found! at index 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultado = false;
while($value = array_shift($nombresArreglo)) {
    if ($nombre === $value) {
        $resultado = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

note: the array `$nombresArreglo` will be empty after this loop is executed, will only work if you don't need this array anymore

Comment: I totally agree with the guy that deleted the comment. :D

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this simply because the OP didn't ask to change the original array.

Comment: This is slightly on topic of what OP requested, but more over not on topic. -1